# ag-grid in jhipster angular 4

Tags: jhipster, ag-grid

i'm trying to use ag-grid in a jhipster project. After adding ag-grid to my project, I imported the module in app.module:

```
{AgGridModule} from 'ag-grid-angular';
```

i modified the component in order to use ag-grid:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { JhiEventManager, JhiParseLinks, JhiAlertService } from 'ng-jhipster';

import { Typapp } from './typapp.model';
import { TypappService } from './typapp.service';
import { ITEMS_PER_PAGE, Principal, ResponseWrapper } from '../../shared';
import {ColDef, ColumnApi, GridApi} from 'ag-grid';

@Component({
    selector: 'jhi-typapp',
    templateUrl: './typapp.component.html'
})
export class TypappComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    typapps: Typapp[];
    typs: Typapp[]
    currentAccount: any;
    eventSubscriber: Subscription;
    /**
     * Declarations AG-GRID
     */
    // rowdata and column definitions
    rowData: Typapp[];
    columnDefs: ColDef[];
    // gridApi and columnApi
    api: GridApi;
    columnApi: ColumnApi;

    constructor(
        private typappService: TypappService,
        private jhiAlertService: JhiAlertService,
        private eventManager: JhiEventManager,
        private principal: Principal
    ) {
        this.columnDefs = this.createColumnDefs();
    }

    loadAll() {
        this.typappService.query().subscribe(
            (res: ResponseWrapper) => {
                this.typapps = res.json;
            },
            (res: ResponseWrapper) => this.onError(res.json)
        );
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.loadAll();
        this.principal.identity().then((account) => {
            this.currentAccount = account;
        });
        this.registerChangeInTypapps();
        /**
         * modif component aggrid
         */
        this.typappService.findAll().subscribe(
            (rowData) => {
                this.rowData = rowData
        },
            (error) => {
                console.log(error);
        }
        )
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.eventManager.destroy(this.eventSubscriber);
    }

    trackId(index: number, item: Typapp) {
        return item.id;
    }
    registerChangeInTypapps() {
        this.eventSubscriber = this.eventManager.subscribe('typappListModification', (response) => this.loadAll());
    }

    private onError(error) {
        this.jhiAlertService.error(error.message, null, null);
    }

    /**
     * AG GRID fonctions
     */
    // one grid initialisation, grap the APIs and auto resize the columns to fit the available space
    onGridReady(params): void {
        this.api = params.api;
        this.columnApi = params.columnApi;

        this.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
    }

    // create some simple column definitions
    private createColumnDefs() {
        return [
            {field: 'id'},
            {field: 'libTyp'},
        ]
    }
}
```

there is the code of component.html

```
<h6> without AGRID</h6>
<div *ngFor="let rd of rowData">
    <span>{{rd.id}}</span>
    <span>{{rd.libTyp}}</span>
</div>
<br/>
<h6> with AGRID</h6>
<ag-grid-angular style="width: 100%; height: 800px;"
                 class="ag-theme-fresh"
                 (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
                 [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
                 [rowData]="rowData">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

and this is the result:
[image]

What i'm doing wrong? why there is no results when i use ag-grid?

Even in the console there is no error.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. Did you import `ag-theme-fresh.css` to `vendor.css`? This did the trick for me.

\src\main\webapp\content\css\vendor.css:

```
...
@import '~ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-theme-fresh.css';
```

Comment: I am also having the same issue, i am using sass so Jhipster by default doesn't provide vendor.css, i tried the same but not working for me any idea ?